# Error While Searching in catalog serach with less than query min length - Magento2

Tags: catalogsearch, magento2.3.2

Searching in catalog serach with less than query min length, I am getting error in Magento 2:

> #1 Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_renderFilters() called at [app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php:408]
>
> #2 Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection->_renderFilters() called at [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php:923]
>
> #3 Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->load(false, false) called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php:803]
>
> #4 Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection->load(false, false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
>
> #5  Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->___callParent('load', array(false, false)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
>
> #6 Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: and what is the actual error reported with this stack trace?

Comment: @Maruti_magento2 i am also getting this issue did you solve this ?

Comment: no...i just keep it 1..and leave it..hence it not showing any error to users..

Comment: @Maruti_magento2 but i think it is not a good way,there is a note " a low query length limit may cause the performance impact."

Comment: yes..but showing error is not good ..then this is ok without error....